# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, c3p0

I am running Spring MVC application with hibernate.cfg as below:

```
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://10.2.10.123:3306/xxx</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">xxx</property>
    <property name="generate_statistics">false</property>
    <property name="connection.password">xxx</property>
    <property name="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
    <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property> 
    <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property> <!-- seconds --> 
    <property name="c3p0.max_size">50</property> 
    <property name="c3p0.max_statements">0</property> 
    <property name="c3p0.min_size">10</property> 
    <property name="c3p0.timeout">7200</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="c3p0.numHelperThreads">5</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
```

When I run application in local environment, it runs without any problem. But on server it gives exception as:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 206,756 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 3 milliseconds ago.

Further I get following log:

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3573)
    ... 90 more
DEBUG: 11:42:41.858 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.trace(BasicResourcePool.java:1644) - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@2b5cccf1 [managed: 7, unused: 6, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@5700187d)
DEBUG: 11:42:41.861 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.decrementPendingAcquires(BasicResourcePool.java:422) - decremented pending_acquires: 0
DEBUG: 11:42:41.858 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:967) - Successfully destroyed resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@61b03322
DEBUG: 11:42:41.861 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.finerLoggingTestPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:323) - Test of PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@c2beb14] on CHECKOUT has FAILED.
java.sql.SQLException: Connection is invalid
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: try to set set auto connect `true` in MySQL connection property.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by increasing value of wait_timeout and interactive_timeout on MySQL server to 3600 seconds(1 hour), which was earlier set as 60 seconds for both.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I faced this error when trying to connect to mysql-server running inside a container on a Ubuntu host VM from the same host.

Example: 
If my VM name is `abc.company.com`,  the following jdbc URL **would not work**:

`jdbc:mysql://abc.company.com:3306/dbname`

Above jdbc url would work fine from other machines like `xyz.company.com` but just not `abc.company.com`.

where as the following jdbc URL **would work just fine** on `abc.company.com` machine:

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname`

which led me to check the `/etc/hosts` file.

Adding the following line to `/etc/hosts` fixed this issue:

`127.0.1.1    abc.company.com    abc`

This seems to be an OS bug that requires us to add these on some Ubuntu versions. 
Reference: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_hostname_resolution

Before trying this, I had tried all other solutions like `GRANT ALL..`, changing the `bind-address` line in mysql.cnf.. None of them helped me in this case.